# Mysql on ubuntu 20.04 access just stops

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have been wrestling with mysql for some time and just did a clean install of ubuntu 20.04 myqsl 8.0 and my lamp server.  got everything back to where I was all running fine and then access denied for user ??? with password (yes).  I had phpmyadmin open on another computer and could see the database's and query etc.  suddenly the screen flashed and all databases were gone except for information schema and performance schema.

All this is running on an odroid hc2.

Any ideas?

This is a snipet of the log file that seams to keep repeating:
2023-05-24T04:07:20.235403Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user . Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2).
2023-05-24T04:07:21.874769Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-24T04:07:45.259225Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011037] [Server] The CYCLE timer is not available. WAIT events in the performance_schema will not be timed.
2023-05-24T04:07:45.944958Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 511
2023-05-24T04:07:46.006695Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-05-24T04:07:48.199207Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-05-24T04:07:49.341163Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-05-24T04:07:49.341278Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-05-24T04:07:49.454209Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-05-24T04:07:49.454402Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-24T04:10:02.652984Z 27 [Warning] [MY-010058] [Server] Hostname 'odroid2' does not resolve to '192.168.1.190'.
2023-05-24T04:10:03.461529Z 29 [Warning] [MY-010055] [Server] IP address '192.168.1.180' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2023-05-24T04:12:08.742579Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user . Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2).
2023-05-24T04:12:10.716031Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-24T04:12:35.176228Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011037] [Server] The CYCLE timer is not available. WAIT events in the performance_schema will not be timed.
2023-05-24T04:12:35.863380Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 511
2023-05-24T04:12:35.926512Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-05-24T04:12:37.884039Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-05-24T04:12:38.821634Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-05-24T04:12:38.821738Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-05-24T04:12:38.964894Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-05-24T04:12:38.965092Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-24T04:12:44.499335Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user . Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2).
2023-05-24T04:12:46.292313Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-24T04:13:08.507230Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011037] [Server] The CYCLE timer is not available. WAIT events in the performance_schema will not be timed.
2023-05-24T04:13:09.228099Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 513
2023-05-24T04:13:09.289705Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-05-24T04:13:11.251616Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-05-24T04:13:12.238469Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-05-24T04:13:12.238627Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-05-24T04:13:12.389984Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2023-05-24T04:13:12.390166Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2023-05-24T04:15:02.595688Z 12 [Warning] [MY-010058] [Server] Hostname 'odroid2' does not resolve to '192.168.1.190'.
2023-05-24T04:15:02.636504Z 13 [Warning] [MY-010055] [Server] IP address '192.168.1.180' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2023-05-24T04:34:38.120792Z 102 [Warning] [MY-010055] [Server] IP address '192.168.1.201' could not be resolved: Name or service not known

Comment: Need to be more specific "wrestling". Alludes to moving files around the place in a way that no official manual even hints at describing. "got everything back" also vague. Databases don't cause screen flashes. Seeing "information_schema" and "performance_schema" could just be using an anonymous user. Include the server logs and significantly more details by editing the question. `SELECT CURRENT_USER(); SHOW GRANTS;` could be useful on your 2 schema view.

Comment: What files are in MySQL's directory?  Were you running 8.0 before the reinstall?

Comment: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost`
GRANT PROXY ON ``@`` TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GR...

Comment: All of the directories are there in /var/lib/mysql

Comment: Wrestling is just a term to trying to get it running again.  I had it running for years and then suddenly I couldn't connect.  so after endless searches and trials I gave up and did a fresh install of Ubuntu, Lamp and mysql 8.0.  It all worked foe several weeks and then same thing couldn't connect.  Phpmyadin was connected and all databases showed up A screen flash (probably unrelated) and all databases disappeared.  phpmyadmin still connects but can't connect with mysql I get an error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'"